# Cant update npm version

Tags: node.js, npm

I was following a course where I was instructed to downgrade my npm version so that both me and the course creator have the same experience.

however, when I tried to run a normal npm i I got this error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v21.2.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\97333\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-26T20_36
```

so I decided to go back to my original version by running
`npm i -g npm@latest`

and got this:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v21.2.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
(node:12004) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js.
Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.

  #  npm[12004]:  at c:\ws\src\node_zlib.cc:585
  #  Assertion failed: args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"

----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 00007FF73C18C11B node::SetCppgcReference+13835
 2: 00007FF73C104826 DSA_meth_get_flags+76758
 3: 00007FF73C104C35 DSA_meth_get_flags+77797
 4: 00007FF73BFF0CD6 RSA_meth_get_flags+110726
 5: 00007FF6DCB8EF5F

----- JavaScript stack trace -----

1: Zlib (C:\Users\97333\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:130:19)
2: Unzip (C:\Users\97333\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minizlib\index.js:323:5)
3: write (C:\Users\97333\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:289:23)
4: ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:1007:22)
5: emit (node:events:519:28)
6: addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
7: readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
8: Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
9: node:internal/streams/transform:178:12
10: PassThrough.enter code here_transform (node:internal/streams/passthrough:46:3)
```

does anyone know how to solve this issue

Comment: Ask the course creator what exact veriosns of Node.js and npm should be installed. Also if you want to work with different versions of Node.js in different projects I'd recommend to use `nvm` to be able to switch between Node versions easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` is "Node Package Manager", and requires Node to be able to run. Downgrading to a version that the version of npm didn't support made it unable to run, as was warned in the terminal. The easiest fix would be to uninstall and reinstall NodeJS.

As was said in a comment: Try using a version manager for Node. On Linux and Mac [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is pretty great. On Windows I'm using [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs). There are multiple alternatives on all platforms.

---

Unrelated to the issue, but as a cause of the issue it's worth exploring some:

While NodeJS and NPM are generally well version-controlled not all open source software is, and you may run into more issues from internal dependencies of example code in the course. When this happens you can try to debug, but that'll be hard if you're just starting. No shame in getting a refund and finding a better course that's not so outdated.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found out the others experienced this issue as well and the fix to this issue was as you said uninstalling and reinstalling NodeJS I really appreciate your help!